# Angular material: apply typography level to material component

Tags: angular, angular-material, typography

I wanted to know if it is possible to apply a typography level to a specific material component from the scss theme. For example, apply the subheading-1 typography to mat-menu component. I am working with version 12 of material.Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible, One thing that can help you is inspect element [this see there's
style section there you can see material classes and modify them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uieao.png)`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I know that I can modify the typography like this, but I need to do it from the scss theme file, to apply the material typography levels

Comment: If you are using scss format then you can check out this documentation -> https://material.angular.io/guide/theming trust me instead of fiddling here and there for the solution it's always better use official guides. reading may seem tedious for a while but you will waste 2 times more time if you keep on hopping on everywhere for the solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have read that documentation, but it is not clear how I should apply my code to do what I need